# Why the below initializer_list function fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

While practicing function with initalizer_list, I am following closely on the book example (on C++ Primer )
Need help to debug why it fails:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <initializer_list>

using std::cout;   using std::endl;
using std::cin;    using std::cerr;  
using std::begin;  using std::end;           /* lib begin and end function (for arrays) */
using std::vector;
using std::string; using std::setw;  
using std::left;   using std::right;         /* align print out result */
using std::initializer_list;

void error_msg(initializer_list<string> il) {
  for(const auto &elem : il)
    cout << elem << " ";
  cout << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  string expected = "Hello", actual = "There";

  error_msg("FunctionX: ", expected, actual);

  return 0;

}
```

It get compile error:

```
g++ -O0 testerrormsg.cpp -lm -o testerrormsg -g -Wall -lpthread -std=c++11
testerrormsg.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
testerrormsg.cpp:27:44: error: could not convert ‘(const char*)"FunctionX: "’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::initializer_list<std::basic_string<char> >’
```

Also, may i ask a couple questions, since it is `initializer_list` related:

1. Note in the above code example (which comes from the book), the arguments are of type "char *, std::string, std::string". So, does it mean that as long as all the arguments are **implicitly convertible** to the declared `std::string` type (in the foo declaration), it is legal?
2. (From the book)"An initializer_list is a library type that represents **an array of values**". I never see such wording before. What difference does *an array of values* have compared to *an array of objects*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An initializer list must be enclosed in braces.

Comment: You should use `error_msg({"FunctionX: ", expected, actual});`.

Comment: @localhost What is it with you and the stupid edits marking everything with `[tag:...]`? Please stop!

Comment: Do you really write `using` for _each_ standard symbol that you use?

Comment: @localhost: I agree with Praetorian; stop writing tags into prose. They do not belong there. [This particular example](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24614692/2) is absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language allows deduction of an `initializer_list<T>` from a *braced-init-list*, which your code is missing. Change the call to `error_msg` to

```
error_msg({"FunctionX: ", expected, actual});
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d37252e49092eae)

---

> So, does it mean that as long as all the arguments are implicitly convertible to the declared `std::string` type (in the foo declaration), it is legal?

Once you fix the function call, that's exactly what it means.

> What difference does an *array of values* have compared to an *array of objects*?

I don't think there's any difference in this context. The standard describes the behavior of an `initializer_list<T>` (§8.5.4/5) as if the implementation has allocated a temporary array containing `N` elements of type `const T`. The `initializer_list<T>` then provides pointers (iterators) to the first and one beyond the last elements of this array.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not passing an initializer list, you are passing three different arguments.

Instead do

```
error_msg({ "FunctionX: ", expected, actual });  // Note the curly-braces
```